# ejb Issue in WebSphere 8

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere-8

We are seeing very weird issue in our environment.

We used to deploy an Application using WebSphere Admin console. Basically this one is an EAR file and during the deployment we used to specify "Database type" as blank in "Provide option to perform EJB Deploy option screen" and in next step we used to choose "MSSQLSERVER_V2005_1" as a backend id.

We are doing this because of following
"If you specify a database type, previously defined backend IDs for all of the EJB modules are overwritten by the chosen database type. To enable backend IDs for individual EJB modules, select the empty choice to set the database type to null."

Ref : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rapp_ejbdeploy.html

Last time some one shutdown the whole server(physical box) and after that we started getting following exceptions in the logs
WSRelationalR I   DSRA8210I: The database product name Microsoft SQL Server may not exactly match with the database represented by the backend ID (DB2UDBNT).

To resolve this issue we tried to do following but issue stands unresolved
1. Stop start the server(JVM)
2. Stop start the Application

To resolve the issue we redeploy the whole application.

We want to find out the exact reason of this one. Any input or thoughts on the same?

Environment information is as follows
WebSphere Application Server ND 8.0.0.9
Windows 2008 R2
Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: This rather looks like someone updated application using different backend ID. If you will be able to recreate problem on test environment, then you should open PMR in the IBM Support.

Comment: Any idea how we can change the backend ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only specify the backend ID during application installation or update. You cannot select a backend ID after the application is installed onto a server. So you would need to reinstall the application.

Check these pages for more details:

- [Backend ID for EJB modules](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_app_bindings.html?lang=en)
- [Select current backend ID settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/urun_app_current_backend_id.html?lang=en)

Since the default backend ID is DB2UDB_V81, maybe someone by accident updated application using the shortcut path, without specifying backend (does you app provide many backends?)